# Как увеличить производительность UICollectionView?

Tags: uicollectionview, xcode, objective-c, ios7

Есть CollectionView, на экране помещается 30-40 ячеек. В каждой ячейке есть один UIView и один UILabel.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TestCell"
                          forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [(UIView *)[cell viewWithTag:1] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    [(UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2] setText:@"10"];
    return cell;
}
```

В данном случае поиск нужного элемента ячейки с помощью "viewWithTag" влияет на производительность не сильно.

При таком примере заметны существенные задержки при прокрутке (iPhone 4 iOS 7.1.2). Если открыть стандартный календарь, то в нём отображается примерно столько же ячеек, но прокрутка плавная.

Немного лучше становится от растеризации:

```
cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

Как можно увеличить производительность?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через drawRect стало работать гораздо быстрее. + Убрал прозрачность там, где это было ненужно.

Answer (score 1):

Пробовали все сделать в drawRect? Обычно в таких случаях помогает. Правда трудозатратно.